# Devise + Omniauth: undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise

I've been following the [omniauth + devise integration guide for facebook](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) and I keep getting this error when I click the link to sign in with facebook link.

undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path` for `#<#<Class:0x0000000253a550>:0x000000035ea490>`

I've double checked the code in the guide and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sendgrid'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'gravatar'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'faker'
gem 'devise'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.15'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

OmniauthCallbacksController:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController



 def facebook

    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

  has_many :likings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :active_relationships, class_name: "Relationship",
                                  foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships, class_name: "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent: :destroy

  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower


  def feed
    Post.where("user_id IN (?) OR user_id = ?", following_ids, id)
  end

  # follows user
  def follow(other_user)
    active_relationships.create(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  # unfollows user
  def unfollow(other_user)
    active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy
  end

  def following?(other_user)
    following.include?(other_user)
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you post your Gemfile? The tutorial uses Devise for authentication, but you may not have added it?

Comment: added the gemfile.  I believe Devise is working because I can register and sign in using my app.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try running rake routes and see what the paths for omniauth are. I believe they have changed with the most recent release of devise.
Try changing

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path %>
```

and see if that works for you.

Apparently the helpers for the omniauth routes have changed since the rake routes command for me returned

```
user_facebook_omniauth_authorize   GET|POST   /users/auth/facebook(.:format)          omniauth_callbacks#passthru
```

and not as it was some months ago when I started the project.

```
user_omniauth_authorize            GET|POST   /users/auth/facebook(:provider)          omniauth_callbacks#passthru
```

You should also change the line

```
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth"])
```

to

```
@user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
```

This is what worked for me, hope this helps.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you very much but now i'm getting a different error.  NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook
undefined method `provider' for nil:NilClass.

Comment: Could you post how the facebook method of OmniauthCallbacksController looks like? Also post your User model

Comment: Edited post to provide controller and model.

Comment: Ah, I think your problem is that you forgot to add ".auth" to request.env["omniauth"]. The first line in the facebook method where you fetch the user should be @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"]). Check the [devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#facebook-example) for setting it up with omniauth-facebook, specifically the OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook section

Comment: Thank you very much.  That worked perfectly.  I should have quadruple checked my code in the first place!

Comment: This is too bad. I depend on the behavior of the original API call, with the parameter for the provider. I use that to generate sign-in links for several providers without duplicating code.

Answer (score 3):

It might not be the answer people are looking for, but you could always just specify an older version of the devise gem in your Gemfile.

`gem 'devise', '~> 4.1.1'`

This took down my production site and I had to act quick. This worked.