# Uninitialized constant OmniauthCallbacksController when trying to sign up user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth, omniauth-linkedin

I'm having an issue with getting OmniAuth to work. I've been following this tutorial [here](http://willschenk.com/setting-up-devise-with-twitter-and-facebook-and-other-omniauth-schemes-without-email-addresses/) to try and implement it with my existing app, but am coming up with the `ActionController::RoutingError at /users/auth/github/upgrade uninitialized constant OmniauthCallbacksController` error. I've looked at several other SO posts but most of those answers deal with misspellings and I've triple-checked that everything is spelled correctly. What might be interfering?

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
                 :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable

  has_many :identities

  def github
        identities.where( :provider => "github" ).first
    end

    def github_client
        @github_client ||= Github.client( access_token: github.accesstoken )
    end

    def linkedin
        identities.where( :provider => "linkedin" ).first
    end

    def linkedin_client
        @linkedin_client ||= Linkedin.client( access_token: linkedin.accesstoken )
    end
end
```

Identity Model:

```
class Identity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :uid, :provider
  validates_uniqueness_of :uid, :scope => :provider

  def self.find_for_oauth(auth)
    identity = find_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid)
    identity = create(uid: auth.uid, provider: auth.provider) if identity.nil?
    identity.accesstoken = auth.credentials.token
    identity.refreshtoken = auth.credentials.refresh_token
    identity.name = auth.info.name
    identity.email = auth.info.email
    identity.nickname = auth.info.nickname
    identity.image = auth.info.image
    identity.phone = auth.info.phone
    identity.urls = (auth.info.urls || "").to_json
    identity.save
    identity
  end
end
```

Devise Model:

```
Devise.setup do |config|

  # config.omniauth :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_APP_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_OAUTH2_APP_SECRET'], scope: "email,profile,offline", prompt: "consent"
  config.omniauth :github, ENV['GITHUB_APP_ID'], ENV['GITHUB_APP_SECRET'], setup: true
  # config.omniauth :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_ID'], ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'], scope: "email"
  config.omniauth :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET'], setup: true
```

Omniauth Model:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do

  provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET']
  provider :linkedin, ENV['LINKEDIN_KEY'], ENV['LINKEDIN_SECRET']
end
```

FormUser Model

```
class FormUser < User
  attr_accessor :current_password

  validates_presence_of   :email, if: :email_required?
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?
  validates_format_of     :email, with: Devise.email_regexp, allow_blank: true, if: :email_changed?

  validates_presence_of     :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
  validates_length_of       :password, within: Devise.password_length, allow_blank: true

  def password_required?
    return false if email.blank?
    !persisted? || !password.nil? || !password_confirmation.nil?
  end

  def email_required?
    true
  end
end
```

Omniauth Callbacks Controller:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def instagram
    generic_callback( 'instagram' )
  end

  def facebook
    generic_callback( 'facebook' )
  end

  def twitter
    generic_callback( 'twitter' )
  end

  def google_oauth2
    generic_callback( 'google_oauth2' )
  end

  def generic_callback( provider )
    @identity = Identity.find_for_oauth env["omniauth.auth"]

    # @user = @identity.user || current_user
    @user = @identity.user || User.find_by(email: @identity.email) || current_user
    if @user.nil?
      @user = User.create( email: @identity.email || "" )
      @identity.update_attribute( :user_id, @user.id )
    end

    if @user.email.blank? && @identity.email
      @user.update_attribute( :email, @identity.email)
    end

    if @user.persisted?
      @identity.update_attribute( :user_id, @user.id )
      # This is because we've created the user manually, and Device expects a
      # FormUser class (with the validations)
      @user = FormUser.find @user.id
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: provider.capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end

  def upgrade
    scope = nil
    if params[:provider] == "google_oauth2"
      scope = "email,profile,offline,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"
    end

    redirect_to user_omniauth_authorize_path( params[:provider] ), flash: { scope: scope }
  end

  def setup
    request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options['scope'] = flash[:scope] || request.env['omniauth.strategy'].options['scope']
    render :text => "Setup complete.", :status => 404
  end
end
```

Registrations Controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create

    unless params["user"]["code"] == ENV["CODE_TO_SIGN_UP"]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { return redirect_to new_user_registration_path, notice: 'The code you entered was wrong. Please contact ' + ENV["ADMIN_EMAIL"] }
      end
    end

    super
  end

  def update_resource(resource, params)
    if resource.encrypted_password.blank? # || params[:password].blank?
      resource.email = params[:email] if params[:email]
      if !params[:password].blank? && params[:password] == params[:password_confirmation]
        logger.info "Updating password"
        resource.password = params[:password]
        resource.save
      end
      if resource.valid?
        resource.update_without_password(params)
      end
    else
      resource.update_with_password(params)
    end
  end
```

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users, class_name: 'FormUser', :controllers => { 
    omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/auth/:provider/upgrade' => 'omniauth_callbacks#upgrade', as: :user_omniauth_upgrade
    get '/users/auth/:provider/setup', :to => 'omniauth_callbacks#setup'
  end

end
```

**UPDATE**
rake routes:

```
Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                             Controller#Action
                new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)                devise/sessions#new
                    user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)                devise/sessions#create
            destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)               devise/sessions#destroy
  user_github_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/github(.:format)            users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
   user_github_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/github/callback(.:format)   users/omniauth_callbacks#github
user_linkedin_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/linkedin(.:format)          users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru
 user_linkedin_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/linkedin/callback(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#linkedin
                   user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#create
               new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)           devise/passwords#new
              edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)          devise/passwords#edit
                                 PATCH    /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#update
                                 PUT      /users/password(.:format)               devise/passwords#update
        cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)                 users/registrations#cancel
               user_registration POST     /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#create
           new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)                users/registrations#new
          edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)                   users/registrations#edit
                                 PATCH    /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#update
                                 PUT      /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#update
                                 DELETE   /users(.:format)                        users/registrations#destroy
           user_omniauth_upgrade GET      /users/auth/:provider/upgrade(.:format) users/omniauth_callbacks#upgrade
                                 GET      /users/auth/:provider/setup(.:format)   users/omniauth_callbacks#setup
                    typing_tests GET      /typing_tests(.:format)                 typing_tests#index
                                 POST     /typing_tests(.:format)                 typing_tests#create
                 new_typing_test GET      /typing_tests/new(.:format)             typing_tests#new
                edit_typing_test GET      /typing_tests/:id/edit(.:format)        typing_tests#edit
                     typing_test GET      /typing_tests/:id(.:format)             typing_tests#show
                                 PATCH    /typing_tests/:id(.:format)             typing_tests#update
                                 PUT      /typing_tests/:id(.:format)             typing_tests#update
                                 DELETE   /typing_tests/:id(.:format)             typing_tests#destroy
                         prompts GET      /prompts(.:format)                      prompts#index
                                 POST     /prompts(.:format)                      prompts#create
                      new_prompt GET      /prompts/new(.:format)                  prompts#new
                     edit_prompt GET      /prompts/:id/edit(.:format)             prompts#edit
                          prompt GET      /prompts/:id(.:format)                  prompts#show
                                 PATCH    /prompts/:id(.:format)                  prompts#update
                                 PUT      /prompts/:id(.:format)                  prompts#update
                                 DELETE   /prompts/:id(.:format)                  prompts#destroy
                    universities GET      /universities(.:format)                 universities#index
                                 POST     /universities(.:format)                 universities#create
                  new_university GET      /universities/new(.:format)             universities#new
                 edit_university GET      /universities/:id/edit(.:format)        universities#edit
                      university PATCH    /universities/:id(.:format)             universities#update
                                 PUT      /universities/:id(.:format)             universities#update
                                 DELETE   /universities/:id(.:format)             universities#destroy
                        programs GET      /programs(.:format)                     programs#index
                                 POST     /programs(.:format)                     programs#create
                     new_program GET      /programs/new(.:format)                 programs#new
                    edit_program GET      /programs/:id/edit(.:format)            programs#edit
                         program PATCH    /programs/:id(.:format)                 programs#update
                                 PUT      /programs/:id(.:format)                 programs#update
                                 DELETE   /programs/:id(.:format)                 programs#destroy
                           users GET      /users(.:format)                        users#index
                       edit_user GET      /users/:id/edit(.:format)               users#edit
                            user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                    users#show
                                 PATCH    /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                                 PUT      /users/:id(.:format)                    users#update
                                 DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)                    users#destroy
                            root GET      /                                       typing_tests#index
            unauthenticated_root GET      /                                       devise/sessions#new
```

Stack trace:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-03 18:24:26 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Session Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "sessions".* FROM "sessions"  WHERE "sessions"."session_id" = '430aa65b41ec7892dd1581f14a9fbd16'  ORDER BY "sessions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 90ms (Views: 88.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "sessions" SET "data" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "sessions"."id" = 45  [["data", "BAh7BkkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjoGRUZJIjFjakIxRFIwRzIxaEl6SkZoNEsv\nMVdGeHZUSGNUS0R0d3cxWFB3aENBbWVjPQY7AEY=\n"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-03 23:24:26.682877"]]
   (6.5ms)  COMMIT


Started GET "/users/auth/github/upgrade" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-05-03 18:24:27 -0500
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#upgrade as HTML
  Parameters: {"provider"=>"github"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path' for #<Users::OmniauthCallbacksController:0x007f9a1e0012b0>
Did you mean?  user_omniauth_upgrade_path
               user_github_omniauth_authorize_path:
  app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:51:in `upgrade'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.9) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:685:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.4.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:562:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.9) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.2.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.4) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.9) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
  /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
  /Users/jimmiejackson/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Please let me know if there is any other code you might need to see. Thanks for your help, this is driving me crazy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have namespaced `OmniauthCallbacksController` under users as `Users::OmniauthCallbacksController`, make sure the controller path is `your_app/app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller‌​.rb` i.e., it resides under `users` folder. Similarly, your `devise` routes should look something like:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

**Note:** `users/omniauth_callbacks`

**UPDATE**

Looking at the routes that you shared, you need to update routes for `upgrade` and `setup` as:

```
devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/auth/:provider/upgrade' => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#upgrade', as: :user_omniauth_upgrade
    get '/users/auth/:provider/setup', :to => 'users/omniauth_callbacks#setup'
  end
```

Again, **note:** `users/omniauth_callbacks`

Comment: They're definitely in the users folder and namespaced correctly. I've added my routes and FormUser model if that's of any help to you.

Comment: @J.Jackson Thanks! That surely helped. Read the Update section on my answer.

Comment: Ah of course, that makes total sense! Now I'm receiving a `undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path' for #<Users::OmniauthCallbacksController:0x007f9a1e0012b0>
Did you mean?  user_omniauth_upgrade_path
               user_github_omniauth_authorize_path` error though. I've added my stack trace and rake routes terminal command. Also, thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ah, figured it out! On my button I was using `user_omniauth_upgrade_path( :github )` but apparently a newer version of devise uses `user_github_omniauth_authorize_path` instead. I found that according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379828/devise-omniauth-undefined-method-user-omniauth-authorize-path) other SO post. Kranti thanks so much for your help with this issue.